# No podspec found for RNStompWS in ../node_modules/react-native-stomp-websocket

Tags: ios, react-native, websocket, react-native-ios, stomp

react-native: "0.61.4"
react-native-stomp-websocket: "^1.0.7"

No podspec found for RNStompWS in ../node_modules/react-native-stomp-websocket.

Getting this issue when I upgraded react native to 0.61.4, It was working in 0.57.7 but not working in 0.61.4
Error pops up while installing pods to the project.

Could you please help me to get out of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Change version in react-native-stomp-websocket->podspec from 1.0.0 to 1.0.7.
This works for me.